# List index out of range when duplicate letter entered

Tags: python

I'm making sort of a hangman game in Python and want to know how I can detect if a certain element is in an index in a list.

For example,

```
wordlist = [a, r, r, a, y]
correct_guesses = [a, r, y]


if letter_guess in word:
        for index in range(len(wordlist)):
            if wordlist[index] == letter_guess:
                if letter_guess not in correct_guesses[index]:
                    correct_guesses.insert(index, letter_guess)
                if letter_guess in guesses:
                    c.clear()
                    guess()
                else:
                    guesses.append(letter_guess)
                    c.clear()
                    guess()
    elif letter_guess not in word:
        if letter_guess in guesses:
            c.clear()
            guess()
        else:
            guesses.append(letter_guess)
            c.clear()
            guess()
```

This returns the error list index out of range
How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code has at least two syntax errors that prevent it from running: an indentation error and an illegal `if` statement.

Comment: At the moment your code example will throw an error: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry, I entered in the wrong code, changed it now
Some variables may not be in here but the code is on https://repl.it/@steamsydev/guess-the-word

Comment: We can't work with this code. The indentation is all over the place and we're missing the full traceback of the error.

Comment: You're trying to use `index` to index into both `wordlist` and `correct_guesses`, which doesn't make sense since they have different lengths.  For instance:  `if letter_guess not in correct_guesses[index]:` is wrong.  Why are you using `index` here at all?

Answer (score 0):

correct_guesses[index] should be correct_guess no [].

If you give the code for c and guess, i can help further

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typical Stackoverflow answer, but I thought I might offer some teaching points about the code snippet you posted. There are a lot of issues in your code, so I thought this approach would be the friendliest way to help you accomplish your task.

(1) Python makes it really easy to iterate through lists.  The more complicated approach in your snippet is reminiscent of C, where a numerical index is incremented. In Python, try:

```
wordlist = [ 'array', 'banana', 'duck' ]
for word in wordlist:
     print word
```

(2) Python makes it really easy to iterate through a string:

```
word = 'foo'
for letter in word:
     print letter
```

(3) To detect if an element is in a list is equally simple:

```
print( 'dog' in [ 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse' ] )
```

(4) To detect if a letter is in a strings continues the same pattern:

```
print( 'g' in 'frog' )
```

The code for word-lists and strings look similar because Python views both lists and strings as subtypes of `sequence`

Good luck on your Python journey.